# Android: android:autoLink=“web” does not support query parameters after domains

Tags: android, url, parameters, dns, autolink

I have a TextView with autoLink set as

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/messageDetail_privateText_txt"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:autoLink="web|phone|email" />
```

But when I set a text with an url like http://www.test.com?p1=v1&p2=v2 the TextView's autolink doesn't recognize the query parameters after the domain.

I can understand that this kind of URL's doesn't have too much sense, but is there any workaround to this problem?

iOS is recognizing the parameters just fine.

Comment: "yourtextview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());" add this on code..

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question, what finally worked for me was to check the urls of the string and adding the slash manually. Not the coolest solution in the world but worked in this case.

Below the code:

```
protected String normalizeURLs(String html)
{

    String[] pieces = html.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> textParts = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String piece : pieces) {

        try {
            URL isURL = new URL(piece);
            String protocol = isURL.getProtocol();
            String host = isURL.getHost();
            String query = isURL.getQuery();
            String path = isURL.getPath();
            String questionMark = "?";

            if (path.equals("")) {
                path = "/";
            }

            if (query == null) {
                query = "";
                questionMark = "";
            }

            String url = protocol + "://" + host + path + questionMark + query;
            textParts.add(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            textParts.add(piece);
        }
    }

    String resultString = "";

    for (String s : textParts)
    {
        resultString += s + " ";
    }

    return resultString;
}
```